# Regex extract text between two text and save the text

Tags: regex

I'm sorry i dont know what keyword should i use for my problem, however i will update my question if someone suggest me better keyword for my problem.

I have this string : `function(goto_url) var(url) str('+url+')`

I use this pattern : `(:?var\((.*?)\))`

Output :

```
Full match : var(url)
Group 1 : var(url)
Group 2 : url
```

Expected output :

```
Full match : var(url)
Group 1 : var
Group 2 : url
```

Any help will apreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-capturing group is set with `(?:` syntax, not `(:?`. You do not need it here though.

Use

```php
(var)\((.*?)\)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/EjCWsj/1).

```php
**Explanation**

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var                      'var'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```

Comment: marked this answer as answered because have explanation, so can you sugget me what keyword my problem, for future people

Answer (score 1):

This work `(var)\((.*?)\)`

https://regex101.com/r/aPGdoS/1

OK for you ?

Comment: thanks, its ok for me, but as stackoverflow rule,you must explain that